# What are the most common places that move semantics is used in C++11 STL?

Tags: c++11, stl, move-semantics

I know that `std::vector<T>::push_back()` has move semantics support. So, when I add a named temporary instance to a vector, I can use `std::move()`.

What are the other common places in the STL that I should grow the habit to add `std::move()`

Comment: "Named temporary"? `emplace_back(some_type{..})` will just do the right thing (after optimization).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I know that `std::vector<T>::push_back()` has move semantics support.

The support that `push_back` has is simply an additional overload that takes an *rvalue reference*, so that the new value `T` inside the vector can be constructed by invoking `T(T&&)` instead of `T(const T&)`. The advantage is that the former can be implemented way more efficiently because it assumes that the passed *rvalue reference* is never going to be used afterwards.

Most Standard Library containers have added similar overloads to their push/enqueue/insert member functions. Additionally, the concept of *emplacement* has been added *(e.g. `std::vector<T>::emplace_back`)*, where the values are constructed in place inside the container in order to avoid unnecessary temporaries. Emplacement should be preferred to insertion/pushing.

---

> So, when I add a named temporary instance to a vector, I can use `std::move()`.

"Named temporary" doesn't really make much sense. The idea is that you have an *lvalue* you don't care about anymore, and you want to turn it into a temporary by using `std::move`. Example:

```
Foo foo;
some_vector.emplace_back(std::move(foo));
// I'm sure `foo` won't be used from now on
```

Just remember that `std::move` is not special: it literally means `static_cast<T&&>`.

---

> What are the other common places in the STL that I should grow the habit to add `std::move`?

This is a really broad question - you should add `std::move` everywhere it makes sense, not just in the context of the Standard Library. If you have a *lvalue* you know you're not going to use anymore in a particular code path, and you want to pass it/store it somewhere, then `std::move` it.